# Issues with Kudan Markerless

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kudan

I have an object that is displayed on my android in AR using Kudan markerless, but when I rotate my phone so its off screen and then back again the object is either not there anymore or has scaled to an undesirable level. Quite simply, once placed I want the object to continue to exist as if it's really in the world. Like AR is supposed to do right?

I have just started with Kudan and I'm running the Markerless Unity tutorial but it doesn't detail any further settings that would make the object seem as if its in real world space. Currently it only seems vaguely real if you don't move the camera that much. Even then the object is quite jittery. Any tips? Thanks

After some experimentation there seem to be a number of other issues with Markerless Kudan:

1/ very erratic frame rates going from 0 - 60 fps with just one object, even after I have halved the screen resolution. There seems to be no reason the fps drops or increases.

2/ Occasionally very long freezes of 15 seconds or more.

3/ Markerless objects always seem to come closer to the camera steadily as if gravitating. They will eventually end up inside/on top of the camera.

4/ They never look at all like they are in the real world. Always shaking and moving around.

5/ If I keep the camera very still and wave my hand around in front of it, this actually pushes the object around the screen. Why on earth would I want that to happen as default behavior? Is that a bug? Surely it should only move when the camera moves/rotates? Can someone explain why this is happening?

Am I doing something wrong or is this technology still way off from being usable?

Comment: I think you need to provide more details because currently you are the only person who see the big picture of you problem.

Comment: I have followed the tutorial here (https://wiki.kudan.eu/Markerless_Tracking). Once my object is placed I move my camera away from it and then back. The object has either scaled up about 20% and moved towards me or completely disappeared (maybe my camera is now inside the object?). Is this expected behaviour with Kudan markerless?

Answer (score 0):

1) Frame rate is dependant on a lot of things.
If you have an old or cheap phone, it could be that your processor simply isn't up to the task.
If you're in an environment that is poorly lit or otherwise difficult to track, then the tracker has to do more work and subsequently there is more load on the processor.
Random frame rate drops in Unity are a problem in many games / apps, just because of the nature of Unity.

2) "Freezes" are essentially just the frame rate dropping to 0. See 1).

3) That simply doesn't happen in any of Kudan's demos, so something else must be going on here, possibly the reasons mentioned in 1).

4) Don't really know what you mean by "shaking", but it isn't something I've seen all that much.

5) Markerless tracking works by tracking the camera image, if you wave your hand in front of the camera, your hand becomes part of the tracked image. If you then move your hand away, the tracker attempts to adjust for the change in its "environment" and move the object in relation to your hand.

Comment: 1- Phone is an LG G4. It's pretty good. I tried both indoor and outdoor environments. 2 - Yes, but why does it do this? 3- I think in all the demos, the device is moved very slowly. Any faster movements and there would be trouble.4 - 'Shaking', I mean when the object moves around a lot. It doesnt seem planted to the floor ever.

Comment: 5 - Seem like the the markerless tracking should only be calculated ONCE then, not update all the time. After my object is placed in the environment I only want my device giro to be changing its position. Surely that would be default behavior and infinitely faster to calculate too, thus alleviating ALL of the above issues?

Comment: Although saying that, it wouldn't be able to re-calculate changes in distance from an object without any reference. Is it possible to tweak the amount of updates per second or set it to once only in Kudan?

Comment: Ok, so it's probably not your processor. Indoor environments are preferred, but it's lighting that has the most impact on how much work the tracker has to do. Too little or too much and it has difficulty distinguishing features. It could simply do less work to find feature points, but the tradeoff would be that in extreme cases it would lose tracking completely.

Comment: Yes, the device is moved slowly in the demos. Spin around in circles and try to distinguish precise features in your immediate environment. It's as difficult for a machine as it is for you to be continually moving and tracking through motion blur, if not more so. Still don't understand "shaking", do you mean the object is always moving, even if you hold the device perfectly still? Have you tried different orientations?

Comment: Kudan isn't interested in replicating Pokemon GO's AR. Tracking updates once every frame. Updating more than once every frame would serve no purpose because the image would not change the second time around, so the tracker would be doing double the work for no benefit. Updating once every 2 or 3 frames would improve the camera rate, certainly, but tracking would become poor in comparison, so you would have a smooth camera feed with awful tracking, which is arguably less desirable than a slightly less smooth frame rate with more stable tracking.

Comment: Okay, so really it sounds like Markerless just doesn't work as it should  yet (ie 3d  that looks like its in the real world). All the obvious issues above are all technical problems that I should just accept as the norm. TBH I simple cant force my end users to move their devices slowly or to give excuses about frame rates etc. Currently I think Kudan does a good job of emulating Pokemon Go, but IMO the tracking on that is awful anyway. It only gets away with it because most of the time the Pokemon are flying around. Needs more work.